# How to deal with date in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table in Sqlite DB having two fields Id and Date (Date is of type Text).
I have stored a few dates in the table from c#. now i want to get the records matching specific day, month and year.
The query i have tried is:

```
select strftime('%m', Date) from testTbl Where id = 3;
```

also:

```
select Date(substr(Date, 0, 10))  as daa from testTbl Where id = 3;
```

but the result of these two quires is always null.. can anyone help me to sort this out?

Comment: What is the date format?

Comment: the default format of c# date field. '8/7/2016 12:00:00 AM'

Answer (score 1):

### Proposed (immediate) fix

Use the following select

```
select substr(Date, 0, 10)  as daa from testTbl Where id = 3;
```

### Cause of the issue

The problem (if you surround the above `substr` with a `Date` function) is that you're using a Text type that is not in the expected [format](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

> **Time Strings**
>
> A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>
> YYYY-MM-DD
>
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
>
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
>
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
>
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
>
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
>
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
>
> HH:MM
>
> HH:MM:SS
>
> HH:MM:SS.SSS
>
> now
>
> DDDDDDDDDD

### Alternative (better) approach

Anyway IMHO, it would be better to create the column with a Date type and to insert values in the following way

```
insert into testTbl values (DateTime("2015-12-31"),3);
```

so that you'll be able to do

```
SELECT strftime('%m/%d/%Y',Date) from testTbl where id = 3;
```

or also

```
SELECT Date from testTbl where Date > DateTime('2016-01-01');
```

from C# the parameterized command would be similar to

```
"insert into testTbl values (DateTime(?),?);"
```

with a parameter value `myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Anyway you *can* actually get the month string with `substr(Date,0,2)` and the year with `substr(Date,5,4)` with your *current* format. I'm simply suggesting an alternative that I would find more *standard* (using the *built-in* `Date` format)

Comment: ok with your first given query i got the date part of the actual string.. now i want to convert it into Date type, and get the month and year from that so that i can compare it and get the result according to given month and year.. how can i do that?

Comment: You're asking it because you don't want to follow the alternative approach when inserting the values? It would be simpler... let me know before I edit again

Comment: i can do that too.. wait let me check it by that way, if thats worked, then no need to edit

Comment: Anyway you can actually get the month **string** with  substr(Date,0,2) and the year with substr(Date,5,4) with your **current** format. I'm simply suggesting an alternative that I would find more *standard* (using the built-in Date format)

Comment: same issue with your alternate approach

Comment: I've **tested** it so there must be some misunderstanding and I've also proposed a selection of date and year with your current format (see my **previous** comment). FYI The following `insert into testTbl values (DateTime("2016-12-31"),3); SELECT strftime('%Y',Date) from testTbl where id = 3;` **does** work